# Block quote and folding in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

#### Block Quote:

In the old version of GoogleDocs there was an option to block quote paragraph, which would create a nice dotted box for the paragraph and make it like a section in a very big doc.

Did anyone find a way to get that functionality with the newer docs, is there any plugin, css for it ?

This link says that there is a way to revert back to old version of docs by Settings (upper right) / Documents / Editing / un-check the box for starting with new formats. I couldnt find that. [The link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=65684fdc8b4607e9&hl=en) is a year old

#### Folding:

In Lotus Notes there was this nice option of folding. You get a small triangle that you can use for folding section of texts. Is it possible to do that in Google Docs and even Outlook for that sake ?

Comment: To workaround all the browser inconsistencies, Google switched over to a SVG rendering model for Docs instead of using HTML. That's why the new version of docs doesn't support raw HTML/CSS editing. I have already raised the issue (and received a response) with Google on GetSatisfaction.com here https://getsatisfaction.com/google/topics/we_need_a_google_docs_format_for_serious_publishing. I'm hoping, with enough support we can get them to bring the old format back under a different name.

Comment: the best you can do is indent the text and apply a background color :(

Comment: Best to limit yourself to one question per Question post.

Comment: I asked the second question that was ignored in another post.

Comment: @EvanPlaice: Also https://getsatisfaction.com/google/topics/how_do_i_make_blockquotes_in_the_new_google_docs

Comment: @EvanPlaice @ endolith "Sorry, the community that you’re looking for has been retired and is no longer available. If you need help, please contact the company you're looking for directly."

Comment: You have at least 3 questions here. You need to split them: One question per question. You can ask as many as you like.

Answer (score 15):

Add a Table and color its background and border how you like.

Below I show a 3-step setup of tables to make it look like an email chain reply.

### Make a Table/s

[image]

### Modify its looks

[image]

### Finished

[image]

Comment: nice - I find that having a blank 'template' table to copy/paste at the end of my document works best, as I can't seem to apply custom styles to a table, or use the paint styles tool

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to format your quote for block quotes is to:

1. Highlight the desired text;
2. Adjust the margin ruler at the top of the page according to the desired spacing.

Once you are done, simply press <kbd>enter</kbd> to start a new line and the margins will be reverted back to the original spacing.

If you are familiar with Microsoft Word, then this should be pretty easy.

Comment: I think tables are easiest. Easier to insert and style.

Answer (score -1):

**[Doesnt work any more]**

I was able to hack this a little:

You can open an old document [which you have still not migrated to the new version] , then go to File => make a copy. Now rename the document and you have a new doc in the old format :). Back to happy days of block quote !!.

This might not last longer though , if google changes something.

Comment: Hopefully they'll bring the old format back. Until then, this is the only option. If you follow my link to GetSatisfaction.com they're aware that a lot of their users prefer the old format and from talking to the Google's rep, it doesn't sound like they're going to disable the old version any time soon.

Comment: This no longer works since they killed the old format completely and force-upgraded to the new one.

Comment: Yeah. I knew there was a time-bomb on this one. Unfortunately dont see an option to delete the answer. I have marked it as no longer working.